# How to change the color of the class in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I have problem with this code , I did every thing with `getElementById` and it works for me. But the same code does not work with

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("hearts");
```

My HTML code is

```js
status = 1;

function changeStyle() {
  //Note the lowercase first letter.
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("hearts");

  if (status == 1) {
    x.style.color = 'white';
    status = 2;
  } else if (status == 2) {
    x.style.color = 'red';
    status = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<a onclick="javascript:changeStyle();" style="color:red;" class="hearts"> my code </a>
```

Comment: one more error is spelling mistake of javascripot

Comment: that because your selector is targeting an element via `ID` not `class`. Look at using `get.ElementsByClassName()` You will need to use a for loop for multiple elements of use `[0]` to select the first element of that class.

Comment: It's amazing the amount of mistakes one can make in only a few lines. Have you considered debugging your code before posting on here?

Comment: Try `var x=document.getElementsByClassName("hearts")[0];`

Comment: your code is working just with the first element what if i have 10 ?

Comment: Also change `onclick="javascripot:changeStyle();"` to `onclick="javascript:changeStyle();"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getElementsByClassName()` method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a `NodeList` object.

The `NodeList` object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0.

Try this:

```
<script>
    status = 1;
function changeStyle() {
    alert(1);
//Note the lowercase first letter.
x = document.getElementsByClassName("hearts")[0];

if(status==1) {
    x.style.color = 'green';
    status = 2;
}
else if(status==2) {
    x.style.color = 'red';
    status = 1;
}
}
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JavaUIDeveloper/nokbpffo/1/)

Comment: this one is working just with the first element
what if i have 10 ? ?

Comment: @user44444 The `getElementsByClassName()` method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a `NodeList` object.

The `NodeList` object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by `index numbers`. The index starts at 0.

Comment: @user44444 : Use a `for` loop

Comment: ok thank you so much :) 
i get the idea now 
i put the index inside my function and the problem is solved